# Create subscription calendar cal.ical from my iOS app with url

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In the iPhone calendar app people can subscribe to calendars from the web and have the events in the calendar, but can my Xcode app generate a local url with an ical file that can be subscribed to? Just for the user on the device with the app, not on the internet?

For example my app when run creates an ical file of events that repeat each year, like international days of the year and puts it somewhere like in the group folder or somewhere behind the scenes and then the user can click that link from within the app or copy and past it into the calendar app by adding a new calendar and putting in the url?

I don't want to put the url online because the information is private and just for the user of the device.

Comment: You would be better to ask for and receive calendar access permissions and add the calendar and events directly using EventKit

Comment: Yes that's an option but since that dates won't be changing much and the user has no need to edit the date or events at all not the option that is the best. Its kind of like the public holiday subscription calendar you can subscribe to

Comment: The problem is your app can't be an iCal server when it isn't in the foreground and the user can't add an ical subscription to their calendar with your app in the foreground.